# Android - duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzafz.class Error

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I got this error when I run the code ->

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>
   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:   
    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
     com/google/android/gms/internal/zzafz.class
```

I have no idea what does it means and do I fix it. I need your help guys
I have treid several things but nothing really helped, I added "`multiDexEnabled true`" and that cause to that error.

Before that error O had "`android error finished with non-zero exit value 2`". After I added "`multiDexEnabled true`", it gives me this error:

"`duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzafz.class Error`"

How can I fix it, any help would be appreciated!

**this is my Manifest**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.world.bolandian.gpstracker"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
   compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
  }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'` and clean-build the project

Answer (score 0):

You are including both the legacy Firebase API:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

and the new Firebase APIs:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
```

They should not be used together.  Remove `firebase-client-android:2.3.1` and follow the instructions in the [Firebase Upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).

It is also important to use the same versions of Firebase and Play Services libraries.  Don't use 9.6.1 of `play-services-maps` and 9.2.1 of the Firebase libs.  The latest versions available are 10.0.1.  Consider updating all of your dependencies to use the latest versions.

**Update:**

I copied the dependencies you posted and was able to reproduce the error.  After I replaced the dependencies with these, the error was resolved.  Do these not work for you?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
}
```

Comment: i tried to delete "compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'" but still got the same error, also change to 10.0.1 - error

Comment: i copied what you did, but still gives me the same error

Comment: Same error is `ZipException: duplicate entry`?  Did you try doing a Clean before rebuilding?

Comment: yea, i cleaned the project and rebuilded it, and still the same error