# duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

Tags: java, android, firebase, sdk

After updated my google play services and google repository, I also updated my firebase sdk and I get this error when I start running the app but when I gradle it no errors was compile.

This is the error I got:

```
Error:Execution failed for task     ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

This is my gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.maecea.ipon4"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 5
    versionName "5.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'

  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

While this is my gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my updated dependencies:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.maecea.ipon4"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 5
    versionName "5.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'

 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40932754/4815718

Comment: It didn't work for me.@qbix

Comment: Try to have same compile versions in your gradle files as you have different versions in it. It will surely help you in resolving the error

Comment: Post your updated dependencies

Comment: Refer this link and update your gradle as you want to https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: The one in the top is my updated dependecies. I used 9.2.0 before @qbix

Comment: I already follow that but I got error again :(

Comment: Im not lying. I used it before. Im trying to update my firebase sdk. @Selvin

Comment: You are still including both the legacy SDK, `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1` and the new SDK, `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1`.  You cannot use them together in the same app.  Read the linked answer again.

Comment: you still have `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'` in your gradle ... so telling that *It didn't work for me* is not true ... maybe you should write *I didn't test it* or *I didn't understand an answer* ... also is `firebase-ui:0.4.0` compatible with `firebase:10.0.1` ? I don't think so ...

Comment: I already delete the com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1 but still I got the same error. @qbix

Comment: We can't see why it's not working if you don't post your updated Gradle files.

Comment: Wtf. I already test it. If you do not believe. Okay fine. I'm asking for some help not for judging me excuse me. @Selvin

Comment: use `./gradlew app:dependencies` ... and check if it is still there or not ... I bet it is ... even if you delete it from gradle becuase some other library depends on it ..

Comment: I already update my question you can see the updated gradle files @qbix

Comment: I didn't changed the gradle project because I don't know if I must change anything @qbix

Comment: I dont know how to use it that ./gradlew app:dependencies @Selvin

Comment: The [FirebaseUI Guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) shows that you need to use `firebase-ui:1.0.1` for compatability with `firebase-database:10.0.1`. Same for `firebase-ui-database`.

Comment: I already changed my firebase-ui to 1.0.1 but I got this error Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0 @qbix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the secondary problem of *Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0*, update your top-level (Project) build.gradle file to include these repositories:

```
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

This is taken from the [project build file](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/build.gradle#L20-L26) for the Firebase UI sample app.

Comment: @Kmmp if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add play services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
```