# Android Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to create a chat app using Firebase, but when I run the code, I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class
```

My grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sebastian.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/41022120/4018207

Comment: did you put firebase jar file in lib folder ?

Comment: @YounasBangash I added firebase using Firebase Assistant

Comment: you are using two version of same library firebase-core:9.8.0 and firebase-core:10.0.1. This may be the issue. try removing one of them.

Comment: @LakhanSharma still no success...

Comment: try to make all the firebase lib of same version

Comment: @YounasBangash how can i do that.?

Comment: also there are two versions for libraries support:design and support:appcompat-v7 try removng them also.

Comment: All android support needs to be same version. All firebase needs to be same version. Firebase UI has different version than the others

Comment: No success.... :(

Comment: please clean project using terminal by command ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!, this a **non-sense** type problem & solution. 
move your

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the top of the file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

......
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey code contains duplicate dependency.

```
compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.8.0'
compile'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
compile'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'  //remove this
compile'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'   //remove this 
compile'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1' //remove this
testCompile'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Hope this help.Happy coding.

Comment: No... still same issuue

Comment: Sync the project and rebuild it and check.

Comment: update the answer please check .You don't have add the v4 dependency if you already have v7. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084808/if-i-use-new-v7-appcompat-library-do-i-still-need-v4-support-library-fo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132750/discussion-between-sagar-gangawane-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase UI has transitive dependencies on the Firebase SDK libraries.  The compatible versions are listed in a table in the [Firebase UI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).  To use the latest (10.0.1) version of the Firebase SDK, you must use version 1.0.1 of the Firebase UI library.  You should also use consistent versions of the Firebase SDK libraries and Support libraries.  Update your dependencies like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Also, to use `firebase-ui:1.0.1` the following change must be made to your project (top-level) build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0

Comment: Did you make the change to the repository list in the project build.gradle?

Comment: I updated my answer to add `mavenCentral()` to the repository list.  See if that fixes it.

Comment: The addition of `maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }` should fix the _Failed to resolve..._ error.  [See here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/392).  Post your project build.gradle.