# Can't Build apk but I can run app on an emulator

Tags: android, gradle, apk

As I mentioned the app runs pretty fine on the emulator but I cant build apk,
the problem should be in this `build.gradle` file ,
I rearranged it after I had some other error but I didn't quite hit the mark

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apak.flancer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is the updated build.grandle(app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apak.flancer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The Error I get is:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class
```

Comment: Open a terminal and execute in your project folder:
`./gradlew clean`

Comment: also you can try this:
`android{

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}`

Comment: I tried both before posting this but didnt work

Comment: Adding this:android{ configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4' all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' } }  gave errors for my imports in the java classes

Comment: Usually when you use `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'` and ` compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'` you have this problem. Can you add the problem that you have after adding the configurtion group to the android module?

Comment: after added configuration group I cant run the app on emulator         
Error:(14, 30) error: cannot find symbol class FragmentManager and         Error:(7, 30) error: cannot find symbol class Fragment

Comment: should I change compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0' directly into compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:25.3.0' and install Respitory

Comment: could you please update your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: do u mean update this post's build.grandle ?

Comment: yupe I want to see where did you put the configuration module...

Comment: Updated, btw thanks for your concern

Comment: [Try this build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/6GxnHJrS) and Update to the `25.3.1` also the problem is  this line `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'` do you need that library? if you need it update it to the version `1.0.2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966843/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-during-packagealldebugclassesformult)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41021286/duplicate-entry-com-google-android-gms-auth-api-signin-internal-zzf-class)

Comment: He mentioned that he tried with those previous post That is why I didn't fagged as a duplicated

Comment: solved this problem I dont know exact solution but I posted my updated build.grandle(app) Other then that I added this:                          repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}                                                                                                              
  to build.grandle(Project level)

Comment: Probably this `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1` component was causing the problem.